Can hg log --patch hide content of deleted files?
I'd like to browse the changes in a Mercurial repo by using hg log --verbose --patch. For file copies (without changes) this results in the desired output, the diff not showing the file contents but rather only "copy from" and "copy to":
changeset:   460:7c89d3672ea7
user:        E. C. Masloch <...>
date:        Sun Nov 17 11:03:13 2024 +0100
files:       src/DOS/buf.nas
description:
copy BUF.ASM to buf.nas, no change


diff --git a/src/DOS/BUF.ASM b/src/DOS/buf.nas
copy from src/DOS/BUF.ASM
copy to src/DOS/buf.nas

However, for file deletion it shows both "deleted file" as well as a diff depicting the entire contents of the file in red (minus lines). I'd like it to not show the entire contents like it does:
changeset:   467:f64bfa494e11
tag:         tip
user:        E. C. Masloch <...>
date:        Sun Nov 17 11:08:30 2024 +0100
files:       src/DOS/BUF.ASM
description:
buf.asm: delete original file


diff --git a/src/DOS/BUF.ASM b/src/DOS/BUF.ASM
deleted file mode 100644
--- a/src/DOS/BUF.ASM
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,984 +0,0 @@
-;      SCCSID = @(#)buf.asm    1.1 85/04/09
-TITLE  BUF - MSDOS buffer management
-NAME   BUF
-; Low level routines for buffer cache management
-;

(Full content cut for brevity.)

Examples are from the repo changesets at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos4/shortlog/f64bfa494e11
